Sources for derivatives of Beta functions?
I have seen expressions for the derivatives of the Beta function such as:
$$\frac{d}{dx} B(x,y)$$
or
$$\frac{d^2}{dxdy} B(x,y)$$
However, anyone have ideas for sources regarding the derivations, because I've also seen something that suggests that there are many approaches.
